# Using Transaction helpful in Android in my scenario?

Tags: android

I am performing two functionalities on my Application

i>Save data (Insertion of data which is quite large)
ii> Data Deletion

I am using SQLite & creating a single database object & referencing it to perform the different database operations. When the application is closing , I am closing the database object.

While saving & deleting the data , its taking approx 4-5 seconds .

I have the following questions:

i>Is opening & closing the database multiple times to handle the database queries a better approach or opening & closing the database only once?

ii>Will using transaction(read on some articles) , while inserting & deleting the data , help me in minimizing the processing time taken ?

If so , kindly provide some sample code/hints for transaction.

Thanks in advance.

Warm Regards,

CB

Answer (score 0):

1) It depends on what are you trying to achieve. If you need to do database updates and update the UI respectively and that's an ongoing process for your application - better leave teh db connection open. If you just do some query to populate data once, or do some inserts - better is to close the database connection as soon as you're finished.

2) Transactions greatly improve speed. Sample code:

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
  // do your db operations here
 ...
 db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
 db.endTransaction();
}
```